# how to custom flip and transition to another view controller with button click ? (n swift)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, flip

basically my current setup is like this
one storyboard ViewController with 3 types of UI View(container, front view, back view) inside of it.

what i want to accomplish (and i don't know how to implement #2)

1. user enters the data on the form(front of the card- View Controller number 1)
2. clicks the save button (do animation flipping and redirect to a new view controller)
3. the new view controller loads up (back of the card - View Controller number 2)

this is the current code flip example:

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var goButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionsSegment: UISegmentedControl!

    let owlImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"img-owl"))
    let catImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"img-cat"))
    var isReverseNeeded = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Transitions Test"
        setupView()
    }

    fileprivate func setupView() {
        let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
        goButton.layer.cornerRadius = 22
        //container to hold the two UI views
        let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250))
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 6/255, green: 111/255, blue: 165/255, alpha: 1.0)
        containerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        containerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        containerView.center = CGPoint(x: screen.midX, y: screen.midY)
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        //front view
        catImageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        catImageView.center = CGPoint(x: containerView.frame.width/2, y: containerView.frame.height/2)
        catImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        catImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        //back view
        owlImageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        owlImageView.center = CGPoint(x: containerView.frame.width/2, y: containerView.frame.height/2)
        owlImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        owlImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        containerView.addSubview(owlImageView)
    }

    @IBAction func goButtonClickHandler(_ sender: Any) {
        doTransition()
    }

    fileprivate func doTransition() {
        let duration = 0.5

        var option:UIViewAnimationOptions = .transitionCrossDissolve
        switch optionsSegment.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0: option = .transitionFlipFromLeft
            case 1: option = .transitionFlipFromRight
            case 2: option = .transitionCurlUp
            case 3: option = .transitionCurlDown
            case 4: option = .transitionCrossDissolve
            case 5: option = .transitionFlipFromTop
            case 6: option = .transitionFlipFromBottom
            default:break
        }

        if isReverseNeeded {
            UIView.transition(from: catImageView, to: owlImageView, duration: duration, options: option, completion: nil)

        } else {
            UIView.transition(from: owlImageView, to: catImageView, duration: duration, options: option, completion: nil)

        }

    isReverseNeeded = !isReverseNeeded

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternatives for transition between view controllers with a flipping animation:

1. You can define a segue in IB, configure that segue to do a horizontal flipping animation:

   [image: flip]

   If you want to invoke that segue programmatically, give the segue a “Identifier” string in the attributes inspector and then you can perform it like so:

   ```
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController", sender: self)
   ```
2. Alternatively, give the actual destination view controller’s scene a storyboard identifier, and the presenting view controller can just present the second view controller:

   ```
   guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondViewController") else { return }
   vc.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
   vc.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
   show(vc, sender: self)
   ```
3. If this standard flipping animation isn’t quite what you want, you can customize it to your heart’s content. iOS gives us rich control over custom transitions between view controller by specifying transitioning delegate, supplying an animation controller, etc. It’s a little complicated, but it’s outlined in WWDC 2017 [Advances in UIKit Animations and Transitions: Custom View Controller Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/216/?time=1386) (about 23:06 into the video) and WWDC 2013 [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218).